# Program to determine what type an user input is

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to make a program that could check if the user input is a number (or what type it actually is). I feel like I am really close to getting it but I can't figure out where I got it wrong.

The problem is actually that the programm only detects integers. Everything past the except statement gets thrown straight down to the "something else" statement. I am not actually getting an error message, it is just that it seems like the if and elif don't work like they are supposed to and won't catch their respective input type. Could somebody give me a solution or a hint?

```
    num = input("please insert a number:\n")
    val = type(num)
    try:
        val = int(num)
        print("Integer", num)
    except ValueError:    
        pass
        if type(val) == float:
            print("float", num)
        elif type(val) == str:
            print("String", num)
        else:
            print("something else", num)
```

Comment: If `val = int(num)` fails then `val` is still `type(num)`, which is `str` (and `type(str) is type`).

Answer (score 0):

The type returned from [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#input) is `str` by default. You can create custom function where you check the type and return it accordingly.

For example:

```
def check_type(num):
    try:
        val = int(num)
        return "Integer"
    except ValueError:
        pass

    try:
        val = float(num)
        return "Float"
    except ValueError:
        pass

    return "String"


num = input("please insert a number:\n")
print(check_type(num))
```

Prints:

```
please insert a number:
2.5
Float
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already solved the problem once with try exepts and wanted to get the task down with "if elif else", just for practice.